# Can I have chance to have student Visa in the UK after my visa was annulled by Schengen?

Tags: uk, schengen, visa-refusals, study

In September 2017, I received Italy Visa for student purpose, however, I had some mistakes in the documents for applying for a scholarship in Italy (these documents did not relate to Visa application). Due to some reasons, I forged a signature for one of the documents (remaining documents had original signatures). They/Italy Consulate-General decided to cancel my Visa with a letter with the reason "the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable".

I know I was stupid, now I am applying for the student visa in the UK for January 2018 semester, will this previous visa cancelation affect my application? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you been accepted onto a course in the UK? Also, any reason not to reapply to the course in Italy? they did think you were worthy of a scholarship before.

Comment: The documents were prepared for submiting schoolarship in Italy, I applied for consular legalization in my country and then, these documents were applied in Italy. I were admitted a course in Italy, and scholarship documents did not relate to Visa documents. I have been admitted by a University in the Uk,and got a small schoolarship. Now, I am waiting for the interview. Can the past affect my application for Visa in the UK? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will **affect** your application. If you are honest this time, you will answer "yes" when they ask if you have ever been refused a visa for any country.

- If you lie and they find out, you can forget about the UK visa application.
- If you tell the truth, there will be **extra scrutiny** of your application. Not an automatic refusal, but it will certainly make things more difficult for you.

---

*Answering the comment, here in the text because of space and formatting:*

I believe the current form for students asks

> 7.3 For either the UK or any other country, have you ever been:
>
> • Refused a visa
>
> • Refused entry at the border
>
> • Refused permission to stay/remain
>
> • Deported
>
> • Removed
>
> • Required to leave
>
> • Excluded/Banned from entry

The idea that you should say "NO" sounds insane to me.

Comment: Thank you! In the application form for the Uk, my agent answer the question about my previous refusal was "NO", because they said my visa was canceled, but not "refused" and I am already tell them my previous Visa was canceled if they ask me. Do you have any ideal?

Comment: @user71090, see above.

Comment: Thank @o.m. - On online form for the Uk application, my agent answer the question "Have you ever been refused a visa to other country?" , my agent said my visa was "Canceled" - which I had visa on my passport and then they canceled, but not I applied for visa and I had no result, so my agent said "NO" for this question. Iam nervous about that, tomorrow I have a interview for my the UK application and I think after that they wil call me for re-interwiewing.

Comment: @user71090, if you mention the cancellation and they say it doesn't matter, you appear overly nervous. If you do not mention the cancellation and they find out, you appear deceptive.